# Symfony production environment throws 500 error: Doctrine\ORM\ORMException 'Unknown Entity namespace alias 'DSBlogBundle'

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm learning Symfony2, really cool stuff. But I do run into some trouble when I want to try and visit the production environment. I have followed the Symblog Tutorial that is located here: http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/

I have cleared the cache and I visit http://symfony.dev/ I have running locally. The page remains totally blank and this error is in the log:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\ORMException' with message 'Unknown Entity namespace alias 'DSBlogBundle'.' 
in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/ORMException.php:236 
Stack trace: 
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php(194): Doctrine\ORM\ORMException::unknownEntityNamespace('DSBlogBundle') 
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php(554): Doctrine\ORM\Configuration->getEntityNamespace('DSBlogBundle') 
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfony/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(194): Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getFqcnFromAlias('DSBlogBundle', 'Blog') 
#3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php(295): Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor('DSBlogBundle:Bl...') 
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfony/vendor in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/ORMException.php on line 236
```

What I don't get is that the `'Unknown Entity namespace alias 'DSBlogBundle'` is perfectly "known" in the development environment. Does anyone know what I am missing? Any help is much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Could you post the `doctrine:orm` section of your `config.yml`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Couple possibilities I can think of:

1) If your code functions properly in the development environment, then it could be a cache problem and/or a permissions problem. Make sure your files are readable by the user/process associated with your web server and make sure the `prod` cache directory is writable by that user so it can generate the necessary files. What I generally do is run the clear cache console command AS that user to avoid unexpected cache problems, like this (on linux):

```
sudo -u www-user php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

If you're developing on linux, you must be logged in as either root or another user with administrator privileges to run a command as a user other than yourself.

2) You may have configurations defined in the `dev` environment that don't exist in the `prod` environment. Double check the files in your `app/config` folder. My first guess would have been that the `DSBlogBundle` wasn't correctly defined in `app/AppKernel.php` but I believe that's environment independent so it couldn't work in dev but not prod.

Comment: Ok! Thanks. I've started working with this and the error message has changed to something that's related to cache folder permissions! Great! I have to go now but I will continue trying later this day! Thanks so far!

Comment: What I eventually had to do is just remove the prod cache folder. Now it's working just fine! Thank you!

Comment: 2nd Point in the answer solved my issue.. Good Catch

Comment: Yes, I had the same problem in Symfony 3. Clearing the cache with this command resolved my issue `sudo php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: First time in 3 years (from symfony 2.3 to 3.x) I see this weird error; clearing the cash solved the problem