# Yet another Unknown Entity namespace alias error (Symfony2, manually created entity)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am having a `[Doctrine\ORM\ORMException] Unknown Entity namespace alias 'src\AppBundle\Entity'`
error message.

A quick search led me to three related SO questions :

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067797/unknown-entity-namespace-alias-in-symfony2) about
a problem in a user-created bundle, which I'm not using here.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25842487/silex-and-doctrine-ormexception-unknown-entity-namespace-alias-semi-fixed) where
the error message is obtained by PHP code rather using doctrine in the command line as I'm currently doing, and

[there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701669/symfony-production-environment-throws-500-error-doctrine-orm-ormexception-unkn) where the answer suggests doing  `sudo php app/console cache:clear --env=dev` ; I did that followed by `sudo chmod a+w app/cache/dev/annotations`, but the problem stayed the same.

Here is what I did  :

1) Successfully create my database with `php app/console doctrine:database:create`

2) Create manually a Product Entity in `app/Entity/Product.php` with the following content (the code below is
copy-pasted from the Symfony Book) :

```
<?php

    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="product")
     */
    class Product
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
         */
        protected $name;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", scale=2)
         */
        protected $price;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="text")
         */
        protected $description;
    }
```

3) Type `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities src/AppBundle/Entity:Product` - which produced the "unknown entity namespace" error message.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `php app/console doctrine:generate:entities src/AppBundle/Entity:Product` This is invalid. The last argument should be `AppBundle:Product` if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: @JovanPerovic Why ? I don't remember the documentation stating anything like that anywhere

Comment: @JovanPerovic You are correct though, if the last argument is replaced with `AppBundle:Product` it works

Comment: There are two syntaxes that are/will be used throughout your `Symfony2` app. One is `\My\Company\Namespace\Entity\Product` and other one is `MyCompanyNamespace:Product`. I believe that putting a `src` anywhere in your code/config would be in violation of `PSR-0`.

`Symfony2` does a very good job of seeing everything thought a bundle. That is why you have to have at least one in your app - everything it a bundle.

Comment: @JovanPerovic OK. Now you can put your comments in an answer and I'll accept it, or I can delete this question, which do you think is best

Comment: I have put up the answer for sake of anyone to stumble upon the same issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two syntaxes that are/will be used throughout your `Symfony2` app.

- `\My\Company\Namespace\Entity\Product`
- `MyCompanyNamespace:Product`

I believe that putting a `src` anywhere in your code/config would be in violation with `PSR-0`. `Symfony2` does a very good job of seeing everything thought a bundle. That is why you have to have at least one in your app - everything it a bundle